# Share a VPN connection via a node in a LAN

Tags: routing, router, nat, route, pf

I would like to share a VPN connection via a node in the same LAN.
The scheme below shows my network system.

```
LAN A: 10.44.247.0/24
|-* Router Aa: 10.44.247.1, ext XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    |-* Node Ab: 10.44.247.2 (en0), ppp 192.168.100.36 (ppp0) -| VPN (L2TP)
    |-* Node Ac: 10.44.247.3                                   | 
                                                               |
LAN B: 192.168.100.0/24                                        |
|-* Router Ba: 192.168.100.1, ext YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY <------------|
    |-* Node Bb: 192.168.100.6
```

What I want to do is to access Node `Bb` from Node `Ac`.
Router `Aa` routes traffic which is destining `192.168.100.0/24`
to `10.44.247.2`. Node `Ab` shares internet connections
with a `pf` service:

```
nat on en0 from en0:network to any -> (en0)
nat on ppp0 from en0:network to 192.168.100.0/24 -> (ppp0)
nat on en0 from ppp0:network to 10.44.247.0/24 -> (en0)
```

I can ping Node `Bb` from Node `Ac`, and the tracted route shows
as expected:

```
$ tractroute 192.168.100.6
traceroute to 192.168.100.6 (192.168.100.6), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.44.247.1 (10.44.247.1)  1.585 ms  0.355 ms  0.325 ms
 2  10.44.247.2 (10.44.247.2)  0.703 ms  0.530 ms  0.545 ms
 3  192.168.100.6 (192.168.100.6)  16.429 ms  13.982 ms  13.834 ms

$ ping 192.168.100.6
PING 192.168.100.6 (192.168.100.6): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 192.168.100.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=14.232 ms
```

Though, I cannot access the node via SSH and other protocols:

```
$ ssh -vvv 192.168.100.6
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.100.6 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.100.6 [192.168.100.6] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/daehyun/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

I do not see any reasons why it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: your NAT rules show you don't expect them to work in **first-match-wins** way, but this is how NAT works in Pf.